# Acumatica - How to add filter PostalCode to Location Selector

Tags: acumatica

We added CustomerLocationID to the Sales Order screen and want to be able to filter it by the postal code as well as the normal LocationID and Location Name.  From what I've read it should be as simple as adding PostalCode to FastFilterFields in the Grid, but it isn't working.  I thought maybe setting AllowSearch to true would work, but it didn't.  Is this actually possible or am I doing something wrong?

`<px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edCustomerLocationID" runat="server" AutoRefresh="True"
    DataField="CustomerLocationID" DataSourceID="ds" >
    <GridProperties FastFilterFields="PostalCode" />
    <GridProperties AllowSearch="True" /></px:PXSegmentMask>`

Comment: do you mean adding the PostalCode column in the selector results?

Comment: Yes...so if I type a postal code into the input for Location...it finds matches from Postal Code column like it does with Id and name.

Answer (score 0):

The PostalCode field is not included in the **Location** table. It is included in the **Address** table.

You can join both tables with this query:

```
Select * from Location
inner join Address
on
Address.CompanyID = Location.CompanyID
and Address.AddressID = Location.DefAddressID
```

In your scenario, you are most likely using the attribute **[LocationID()]** for your field. That attribute is encapsulated and it is not a straightforward modification.

I would recommend re-defining the field's attributes with basic attributes i.e.

[PXDBInt]

[PXUIFIeld], etc.

And for the Selector, make sure you join the 2 tables with the join condition included above.
Be aware that this should be a [PXDimensionSelector] with DimensionName = "LOCATION"

Comment: @Rowan I am reviewing the Stackoverflow answers. Were you able to test this?